# How build table with summary rows and multigroups using CSS/JS/HTML

Tags: css, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to build table using:
- CSS
- JS
- HTML5

Above is not an issue. But I want table with functions:
- summary rows
- multigroups
- custom aggregates

I am searching for alike pivot table from MS Excel.

Is there any framework (open source) that could help me ?

Examples of what I search (Silverlight example):

http://leeontech.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/sr2.png
http://leeontech.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/sr1.png

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Where did you get stuck in your code?

Comment: I am total noob in JS/CSS. So I searching for ready framework. If there is nothing open source, then i would like some tips how start with that. For building datagrid use ul/li or table elements ?

Comment: @gather create google spreadsheet and embed it to your page — it is the best and fastest solution

Comment: It could be fast - a really good idea. But a solution is for intranet app and for safety reason the data cannot be storage on third party databases.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and its plugin [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) will do the trick for you. Look for examples on respective websites, it has some features you seem to need (sorting, 'summary rows', etc).